# Can Rails 4 do nested queries with ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've written a new SQL query for some stats analysis in my Rails 4 application. I'd prefer for it to be expressed in an ActiveRecord query rather than SQL for the purposes of maintainability, readability, and consistency, but I can't work out how to.

I've found some code using nested `JOINs` but none for nested `SELECTs`.

I have a table called `groups` which has a one-to-many relationships with `group_members` (these are also ActiveRecord objects Group & GroupMember).

I'm trying to calculate the number of groups with X amount of members, across all member counts. This is for a distribution graph showing how many members groups have.

This is the query that I wrote and that is currently running using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query`:

```sql
SELECT members_count, COUNT(members_count) 
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS members_count, "group_id" AS group_id 
      FROM "groups" 
      INNER JOIN "group_members" ON "group_members"."group_id" = "groups"."id" 
      GROUP BY "group_id"
     ) AS groups_count 
GROUP BY members_count 
ORDER BY members_count;
```

**How can I convert this into an ActiveRecord query?** The issue I'm butting up against is the nested `SELECT` calls. Can this be achieved in ActiveRecord in Rails 4?

Comment: In case it's helpful, this is the type of graph that is being generated: https://imgur.com/a/JhEGTkp

Comment: One approach you may want to look into (that is slightly different and has caveats) is the [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO leave the gems for when you really need them.

You can combine a subquery with `from` and `select`:

```
Group
  .from(
    Group
      .joins(:group_members)
      .select('COUNT(*) AS members_count, group_members.group_id')
      .group('group_members.group_id')
  )
  .select("members_count", 'COUNT(members_count)')
  .group("members_count")
  .order("members_count")

# SELECT "members_count", COUNT(members_count)
# FROM (
#   SELECT COUNT(*) AS members_count, group_members.group_id
#   FROM "groups"
#   INNER JOIN "group_members" ON "group_members"."group_id" = "groups"."id"
#   GROUP BY group_members.group_id
# ) subquery
# GROUP BY "members_count"
# ORDER BY "members_count" ASC
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea the `.from` method existed. I had to tweak the `.joins` as the association is named `members` and I wanted an inner join. The only other thing was the outer group/order - using the symbol syntax meant the parser tried to use "groups.members_count", so I switched to using "members_count" in all the outer statements, which worked. I'll edit your post to make that clear

Comment: Sure, update it as needed to fit your case. Glad to help (;

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend steering away from the ORM and towards something like SQL Views for this.

There's a fantastic gem for interacting with SQL Views in ruby called Scenic: https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic

Performance is one obvious reason, but I also think you'll find it's actually easier to reason about these kind of problems in SQL. ActiveRecord should be a tool to help you not have to write the really silly little queries, not to eliminate raw SQL from your app entirely.

That being said, `select` can handle nested queries the same as `join` in ActiveRecord.

Comment: If you want to use AR to it's fullest extent and avoid sql string munging (which can lead to injection issues), check out [Arel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/arel) and [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)

Comment: Thanks sevensidedmarble and Garrett. I'm marking the ActiveRecord answer as the solution as it's what I was directly asking for, but those gems are really interesting and I will definitely have a think about how we do these kind of queries. You're definitely right about reasoning here sevensidedmarble - I've been writing SQL then converting it into ActiveRecord syntax for a lot of these stats queries